# How to Make REST API call in WCF Service?

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I need to implement a WCF service which when called upon calls a Rest API.
For Eg. This is the Service Model Interface

```
using System.ServiceModel;  
namespace Calc  
{  
 [ServiceContract]  
 public interface ICalcService  
 {  
  [OperationContract]  
  string getresponse(int id);  

 }  
}
```

And This is Implementation

```
 namespace Calc  
    {  
     [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]  
     public class CalcService: ICalcService  
     {  
      public string getresponse(int id)  
      {  

//what I want to do is this

           HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
            string baseUrl = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/";
            string queryFilter = "?fields=name;capital;currencies";
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your country name:");
            string searchTerm = Console.ReadLine();
            string url = baseUrl + searchTerm + queryFilter;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(new Uri(url)).Result;
            return response.ToString();

      }  

     }  
    }
```

The problem which I face is, we need to use await while calling to rest API. But for that we need to change the method "getresponse" to async and that's not working as the definition is derived from the interface ICalcService. I tried changing the same method definition in interface, but that again was not allowed.

What can be a solution here?

**What I want is a simple call to my WCF service which itself calls a REST API, Gets the result and returns to the callee.**

Can anyone provide any solution?

Comment: But what you have here, works. If you can't change the method signature, you'll have to block on the async call, which is what this code does. What's the problem?

Comment: @CodeCaster For this to work, we need to declare the get response method async which we can't do since it directly implements the definition of interface ICalcService. When we put async in definition of the method in interface, we get issues.

Comment: The code you show is not async. What's the problem with it?

Comment: The code won't work this way. Http.GetAsync() is an asynchronous method.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You can't say something "won't work" when it's obvious it does. Instead of `var foo = await FooAsync()` you can also say `var foo = FooASync().Result;`, calling it synchronously. It has its own load of problems, sure. But if you want help, you have to mention why it doesn't.

Comment: @CodeCaster : When I don't use await, that would give me no values in Content. It's obvious it should have worked but it's not giving values which should be there in response.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little confused on your question if you want to perform the method asynchronously. We have to modify the service contract.

```
[OperationContract]
Task<string> GetResponse(int id);

public async Task<string> GetResponse(int id)
{
    Task<string> task = new Task<string>(() =>
      {
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
          return "Hello";
      });
    task.Start();

    return await task;
}
```

If we want to perform the method synchronously, just like you do.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(new Uri(url)).Result;
            return response.ToString();
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.